# How to solve the key error in python with a attacked csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is my code for login in the program as an admin

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("-:-:-:-:-Welcome to Oum Cloth Store-:-:-:-:-")
m=1
while(m==1):
    print("1.Admin")
    print("2.User")
    a=int(input("Enter your choice"))
    if(a==1):
        ad=input("Enter Admin Name")
        pa=input("Enter Password")
        df=pd.read_csv('Admin.csv')
        print(df)
        df1=df[(df['Admin']==ad) & (df['Password']==pa)]
        if(df1.empty):
            print("Admin Not Exists")
            print("Please Enter Correct Details")
            m=1
```

And here is the CSV FILE

```
Admin   Password
Diya      Di
```

And while running it is showing Keyword error for the 'Password' column.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Diya/code.py", line 16, in <module>
    df1=df[(df['Admin']==ad) & (df['Password']== pa)]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Password'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv` files are `comma separated values` files. Since you are not separating the values with commas I would check the `sep` parameter in `pd.read_csv()`